# Why is the ipython output of set different from the __repr__ or __str__ of the set?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I am running the following code in ipython and am surprised at the print outputs and the ipython cell outputs of the code:

```
print set(["A", "B", "C"])
print set(["A", "C", "B"])
print list(set(["A", "C", "B"]))
print list(set(["A", "B", "C"]))
print [k for k in set(["A", "C", "B"])]
print [k for k in set(["A", "B", "C"])]
a = set(["A", "B", "C"])
print a
print a.__repr__()
print a.__str__()
print [(k, hash(k)) for k in a]
a
```

The output of the above program is as follows:

```
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
['A', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'C', 'B']
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
[('A', -269909568), ('C', -13908798), ('B', -141909181)]
Out[34]: {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Note, that the cell output is `{'A', 'B', 'C'}` while the printed output is `set(['A', 'C', 'B'])`

My Python details are as follows:

```
import sys
print sys.version
2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 14:26:21) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 2):

IPython uses a different print function:

```
In [1]: from IPython.lib.pretty import pprint

In [2]: a = set(["A", "B", "C"])

In [3]: pprint(a)
{'A', 'B', 'C'}

In [4]: a
Out[4]: {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Answer (score 1):

IPython adds some magic from time-to-time to make things more readable.

In this case it's showing you a set literal (new in python2.7)

Here's the code that makes that happen:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/f49962dc931870a1eba4b6467ce302c8ae095b3f/IPython/lib/pretty.py#L560

Answer (score 0):

That is because a `set` is an unordered sequence.  When you define the `set`, it is not ordered.  When you try to print it, it needs to come up with some way to order it, but it is unrelated to what order the elements of the `set` were given.  Also, when you try to create a `list` from the `set`, it needs to come up with some order.  What order it comes up with will always be the same, but it is completely unrelated to what order the elements are given.